# Using TBD62083 to drive LED array from CPLD

Tags: led, led-driver

I am looking for a cost effective way to drive 6 seven segment LEDs and 20 discrete LEDs from an Altera Max V CPLD.  The CPLD has I/O voltage of 3.3V and 4mA drive and the Common Anode seven Segment display has Vf=4.0V and If=20mA.  After considering Fets, transistors and other options I have settled on the Toshiba TBD62083AFG 8x DMOS transistor array with a 39ohm resistor between it and the LED.  At $0.52 ea it seems the most economical and I have room for the rather large 18SOIC pkg.  Does anyone have any experience with this part in this application or have a better part in mind?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been abandoned by the asker and was always largely a "shopping" question.

Answer (score 0):

TBD62083AFG is well suited for your purpose.

ULN2803 replaced by TBD62083AFG is used for years in this way.

If you think to multiplex the LED-s you can use a TBD62083AFG that sink current and a TBD62781APG that source current and only 16 outputs.